# How to sync gopass password store to an android device?

Tags: password, password-store, keepassx

I have setup [gopass](https://github.com/gopasspw/gopass) to be my password manager on my arch linux desktop. I would like to sync the password store to my Android mobile device.

Is the only way to create a remote git repo on GitLab/Bitbucket and sync the passwords that way? Is there any other way? I would rather not have my passwords pass through 3rd party hosts.

Comment: @Rui F Ribeiro is the original statement 'if that is in any way possible' flouting any rules that you had to edit it out?

Answer (score 0):

For posteirity's sake, I found these 2 options listed in the link below to sync the password-store to my other machines.

[gopass usage](https://github.com/gopasspw/gopass/issues/914)

I used my self hosted cloud to sync the password-store and then using gpg to import the public and private key to my other machines.